# Adding a linear layout in XML dynamically to another linear layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Basically I created a separate XML containing a linear layout which contains a image and a textview, and I need this linear layout inside of another linear layout, where I need to add my first linear layout dynamically to the second linear layout.

First linear layout, a separate XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/storeLocation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/settings_item_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/settings_item_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="@integer/sales_order_settings_visibility"
        style="@style/dashboard_btn"
        android:onClick="onStoreLocationClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/settings_item_image_container_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/setting_item_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/setting_item_image_size"
                android:tint="@color/cherry_red_without_opacity"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:gravity="center|left">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Store Location"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/top_section_purchase_id_font" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Second linear layout, separate XML:

```
<LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/settingButtonHolder"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Android Studio code:

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settingButtonHolder);
            linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.storeLocation);
            linearLayout.addView(linearLayout2);
```

This doesn't work, I am getting a null pointer exception :

```
12-16 16:48:52.402 21571-21571/io.apptizer.business.clover E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.apptizer.business.clover, PID: 21571
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.apptizer.business.clover/io.apptizer.pos.activity.ApplicationSettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3353)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
        at io.apptizer.pos.activity.applicationSetting.ApplicationSettingsActivityCommon.onCreate(ApplicationSettingsActivityCommon.java:151)
        at io.apptizer.pos.activity.ApplicationSettingsActivity.onCreate(ApplicationSettingsActivity.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: 1. Where do you call the method? Are the layouts in an activity or fragment? Are you trying to "add" in an activity or fragment?

Comment: 2. You can also use the ```include``` tag, and then change its visibility.

Comment: 3. Your LinearLayouts are separate xml files so you can't add them as views.

Comment: Why don't you create the separate xml into a dynamic layout ? Just use the same views from separate xml then add to your main layout.

Comment: Further explanation of your NPE: you do not have a view with id "storeLocation" inside the activity/fragment you are working in, thus the NPE. You either need to add it as a Fragment or in an Include tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the layouts must not exist as a view yet. If your activity or fragment is being built with `settingButtonHolder` layout then you need to inflate the other layout using a `LayoutInflater`.

Once you've used the `LayoutInflater` you will receive a view instance which you can use to add to your linearlayout in the place of `linearLayout2`. Until you've inflated your new layout, you will keep seeing NPEs because the views in that layout will not exist. You will have to use your inflated view instance (`linearLayout2`) to access the views, preferably through `linearLayout2.findViewById(R.id.X)`.

Try this out and let me know if it has helped you at all, Panos.